# grep - Print line with matching pattern, starting from the matched pattern

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

For e.g. If I have a file containing:

```
spam eggs ham
```

and I do `grep <some-flag> "eggs" *`

I should get the output as:

```
eggs ham
```

and not

```
spam eggs ham
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 $ echo "spam eggs ham" | grep -o 'eggs.*'
 eggs ham
```

- `grep -o`
  This is used to print only the matched portion of text.
- `eggs.*`
  This means , eggs followed anything ( dot notify any character and star means zero or more match)

Comment: Thanks! What does `.*` do? Why doesn't `*` only work correctly here?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. One improvement I found was adding `-h` that suppresses filename prefix.